# Ways to run python script in the background on ubuntu VPS and save the logs

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, cron, nohup

So, I have a python script which outputs some data into terminal from time to time. Im trying to run in on the Ubuntu VPS even after I close the SSH connection and still keep the logs somewhere.

Im saving the logs by using:

```
python3 my_script.py >>file.txt
```

and it works perfect, however when I try to run this process using

```
nohup python3 my_script.py >>file.txt &
```

so it runs in the background and after the ssh connection is closed it seems to save only the first log outputted from my_script.py. I've also tried running this in *crontab* but the result is similar - only the first log is saved.

Any tips? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not understand what you mean "the first log". Maybe the first line of logs?

To run something in the background when SSH connection is closed, I prefer Linux `screen`, a terminal simulation tool that help you run your command in a sub-process. With it, you could choose to view your output any time in the foreground, or leave your process run in the background.

### Usage (short)

`screen` is not included in most Linux distributions. Install it (Ubuntu):

```
$ sudo apt-get install screen
```

Run your script in the foreground:

```
$ screen python3 my_script.py
```

You'll see it running. Now detach from this screen: Press keys `Ctrl-A` followed by `Ctrl-D`. You'll be back to your shell where you run previous `screen` command. If you need to switch back to the running context, use `screen -r` command.

This tool supports multiple parallel running process too.

### Something weird

I've tried to redirect `stdout` or `stderr` to a file with `>` or `>>` symbol. It turned out in failure. I am not an expert of this either, and maybe you need to see its manual page. However, I tend to directly write to a file in Python scripts, with some essential output lines on the console.